# Error in web service PHP

Tags: php, android, web-services, login-script

It's my first post here so hi all.
I'm developping an android app for my website so I need login page , I'm trying to use a PHP web service to do that but I'm facing an error now and can't move on.

**First code block:**
Simple code send email and password and test but it give me error "Login credentials are wrong. Please try again!"

**Second code block:**
I try to set email and password manually in the web service and it works , I don't know why the first code doesn't work , even I have tested the email and password from the first code in my mobile when testing and they are showing correctly.

Here is the first code block:

```
<?php


require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    // receiving the post params
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password']; 


    // get the user by email and password
    $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);

    if ($user != false) {
        // use is found
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["user"]["id"] = $user["id"];
        $response["user"]["username"] = $user["username"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["date_creation"] = $user["date_creation"];
        $response["user"]["date_modification"] = $user["date_modification"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user is not found with the credentials
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Login credentials are wrong. Please try again!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
 } else {
    // required post params is missing
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters email or password is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
} 
?>
```

Second code block:

```
    <?php

 require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
 $db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    // receiving the post params

    //manually
     $email = 'amin_saad19@yahoo.fr';
    $password = '123'; 

    // get the user by email and password
    $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);

    if ($user != false) {
        // user is found
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["user"]["id"] = $user["id"];
        $response["user"]["username"] = $user["username"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["date_creation"] = $user["date_creation"];
        $response["user"]["date_modification"] = $user["date_modification"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user is not found with the credentials
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Login credentials are wrong. Please try again!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
 } else {
    // required post params is missing
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters email or password is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
} 
?>
```

Comment: Make sure you are performing a POST request, the values are keyed with the correct names, and values are populated correctly. You can use printr() to inspect the values in your testing.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to dump the values of $email, $password and $user -
 `var_dump( $email ); var_dump( $password ); var_dump( $user );` and post the result.

Comment: $email and $password are populated correctly , i will try to show $user but i don't think that is the problem

Comment: Please also provide what value is showing for $user as this seems to be evaluating to false, this will be useful for anyone trying to help.